# Using Ghost4j to convert PDF to TIF in web application

Tags: java, ghostscript, ghost4j

I am using Ghost4j in a web application to convert PDF to TIFF. While doing performance testing on my application I discovered that when multiple PDF documents need to be converted it takes a long time. After further research I found this part of the documentation:  http://www.ghost4j.org/threadsafetyandmultithreading.html

However, I'm confused whether I should be putting my code in `synchronized` block as well as use `setMaxProcessCount()` ?

Here is how I'm doing it at the moment:

```
    PDFDocument lDocument = new PDFDocument();
    lDocument.load(new File (pdfFilePath));
    SimpleRenderer lRenderer = new SimpleRenderer();
    lRenderer.setResolution(300);

    // render as images
    List<Image> lImages = lRenderer.render(lDocument);
```

**Question**

- How would I make this work in a web application that gets multiple requests.

Comment: did u get it solve i also want this for my rails web application ?